# Retrieving data attribute of clicked item, jQuery & ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

New to ES6. Trying to grab data attribute of clicked link. HTML:

```
<ul class="home-news-slider-categories">
  <li><a href="#" data-slide="1">Slide 1</a><li>
  <li><a href="#" data-slide="2">Slide 2</a><li>
  ...
</ul>
```

In my JS, I've written a test function to grab the `slide` data attribute on a given item when clicked:

```
$('.home-news-slider-categories > li > a').click((e) => {
  console.log($(this).data('slide'));
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The event is being fired whenever I click a link, but the console is returning `undefined` each time.

Am I using $(this) incorrectly?

Comment: Use standard function notation instead of arrow function notation. The latter does not alter the `this` context.

Comment: Exactly, you can also use e.targetElement to know which element was clicked instead of changing, this.

Comment: If you console.log $(this) inside your jQuery function, you'll see the problem.  $(this) isn't an a link element, like you're expecting it to be.